# System.Net.Http.HttpClient cannot connect to web API via NSwag client (Windows Universal Platform)

Tags: c#, api, http, uwp, nswag

I wrote a simple `.Net Core 3.0` API using `Swashbuckle Swagger` and generated an api client via `NSwag Studio`, then I put a generated Api Client to a .Net Standard 2.0 project.
I have a Universal Windows Platform application, which is meant to be connecting to the Web Api and send/receive data etc.

I put a simple code in `MainPage.xaml.cs` class with `System.Net.Http.HttpClient` inside

```
public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        var httpClient = new HttpClient();
        var apiClient = new ApiClient(ProjectConstants.API_URL, httpClient);
        var deviceService = new DeviceService(apiClient);
    }
```

When API is called later in deviceService my program throws an exception on `SendAsync` method in generated Api Client

> "An error occurred while sending the request."

`var response_ = await client_.SendAsync(request_, System.Net.Http.HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead, cancellationToken).ConfigureAwait(false);`

I tested API Client and HttpClient on .Net Core console app and it worked fine.
I read about Http Client for UWP https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/networking/httpclient but it seems UWP should support `System.Net.Http.HttpClient` too, which I would love to stick to.
Is this a Universal Windows Platform bug or do I forgot about adding something necessary to a project?

Answer (score 0):

The `System.Net.Http.HttpClient` API can be used across platforms, but we do recommend using APIs from `Windows.Web.Http.HttpClient` NameSpace which is easy to use. So you could use `Windows.Web.Http.HttpClient` API in UWP,and use `GetAsync`(`PostAsync`) to send a request, for example:

```
Uri requestUri = new Uri("http://www.contoso.com");
Windows.Web.Http.HttpClient httpClient = new Windows.Web.Http.HttpClient();
Windows.Web.Http.HttpResponseMessage httpResponse = new Windows.Web.Http.HttpResponseMessage();
httpResponse = await httpClient.GetAsync(requestUri);
```

For more information about the differences between Windows.Web.Http and System.Net.Http.HttpClient, you can refer to this [article](https://blogs.windows.com/windowsdeveloper/2015/11/23/demystifying-httpclient-apis-in-the-universal-windows-platform/)

Comment: Well, 
"Do you intend to write cross-platform .NET code (across UWP/ASP.NET 5/iOS and Android)?
If yes – then use System.Net.Http API. This allows you to write code that you can re-use on other .NET platforms such as ASP.NET 5 and .NET Framework desktop applications. "
I should stick to `System.Net.Http.HttpClient` in my projects

Comment: @Hantick Why you add `ConfigureAwait` after `SendAsync` that already use await key word?

Comment: @NicoZhu-MSFT it is auto-generated by NSwag

Comment: @Hantick, could you try to remove `ConfigureAwait` and test again?

Comment: @NicoZhu-MSFT I removed `.ConfigureAwait(false)` everywhere, no effect :(

Comment: @Hantick, Sorry to head that, but in uwp platform we suggest `Windows.Web.Http.HttpClient`  to used, if you want to make cross platform lib, you need implement httpclient separately base on `Windows.Web.Http.HttpClient`.

Answer (score 0):

Does it have the same api as the portable HttpClient?